# How do I "combine" two UIImageViews into one image? Like Photoshop Layer merging?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawing

I have a drawing app where you have one UIImageView that serves as the "drawing layer." You have another UIImageView beneath it that is the "image layer," containing the image you are drawing on. I like having this separation. However, I want the user to be able to "save and email" the drawing they have made on top of the image as one unified image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Your `UIImageView` instances must be part of a `UIView` hierachy so all you need to do is paint that top containing `UIView` into a context

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));

[container.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *fimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

or if that gives you trouble successively paint the two images into a context

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));

[image1.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[image2.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *fimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

from there you can write the data where you choose

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(fimage);
```

Pass that data into the MailComposer setup.

Comment: Been looking for that renderInContext method all day. Thanks so much!